# Remove Padding from antD Dropdown menu item

Tags: html, css, reactjs, antd

There is no prop to apply styles to an ant design menu item. I need to remove padding by altering the antd styles of menu item but my selectors are not doing that:
[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-antd-popconfirm-bug-fix-sgsncd?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A8%2C1-25%2C8)

```
const StyledDropdown = styled(Dropdown)`
     .ant-dropdown-menu-item.ant-dropdown-menu-item-only-child {
      padding: 0px !important;
      }
      li.ant-dropdown-menu-item {
      padding: 0px !important;
      }
      .ant-dropdown{
      padding: 0px !important;
      border: 2px solid red !important;
      }
      .ant-dropdown-menu{
      padding: 0px !important;
      border: 2px solid red !important;
      }
      .ant-dropdown-menu-item {
      padding: 0px !important;
    }`;
```

I am attempting to remove this padding, so my button occupies the entire menu:
[image][image]

Comment: If your project includes an "index.css" file, you can incorporate the desired styles into it. Alternatively, if the file doesn't exist, you can create one and proceed to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use style attribute in menu items -> [sample](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sandpack-project-forked-7rsf6z?file=%2Fapp.tsx%3A1%2C1-36%2C1)

```
import React from "react";
import { Row, Col, MenuProps, Dropdown, Space } from "antd";

export default () => {
  const items: MenuProps["items"] = [
    {
      label: "1st menu item",
      key: "0",
      style: { padding: 0 },
    },
    {
      label: "2nd menu item",
      key: "1",
    },
    {
      type: "divider",
    },
    {
      label: "3rd menu item",
      key: "3",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Row gutter={[24, 24]}>
      <Col span={24}>
        <Dropdown menu={{ items }}>
          <a onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
            <Space>Hover me</Space>
          </a>
        </Dropdown>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};
```